# URL rewrite not found

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL it's like this

http://domain.com/validar/api.php?desde=email&que=test@mail.com

and i want to rewrite url's like this

http://domain.com/validar/email/test@mail.com/

I thought this was the way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /validar/
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$/api.php?desde=$1&que=$2 [L]
```

But i'm getting 404 and cant make it work

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove leading `/` from your rule and don't get why you have `mail/` in your target URI since it is not shown in your question.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /validar/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ api.php?desde=$1&que=$2 [L,QSA]
```